# SQL Server DATE vs INT as primary key

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a reference table which will be keeping track of a given range of dates over a large number of years, with the most granular level being a given day. 
Several colleagues have advised me to use a surrogate INT as a key, with the format of YYYYMMDD. While that does seem to be the logical course, I was wondering about using the simple DATE datatype as a PK instead of the INT. My reasoning for this is two-fold:

1. DATE displaces 3 bytes of data, whereas an INT displaces 4. While this is not exactly saving much in terms of space, it can save an awful lot in terms of performance. Considering that this table will have covering non-clustered indexes as well, the size of the primary key is quite important as well (hidden index columns).
2. Since the context in which this data will be used does indeed revolve around dates, I am worried about conversions between INT and DATE. On a small scale, it doesn't make much of a difference; however, once we scale up it may be noticeable.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Just to validate your idea about using `date` instead of `int`? Personally I do agree with you, always try to use the correct type where possible. It also adds a constraint to ensure no "bogus" data is entered (February 30th for example). It is also easier to query and you can use built in date functions.

Comment: Go with `Date`, no question about it. 
No need for a surrogate key if your dates are unique.

The main benefit is your second point - no need for conversions between dates and ints.

Comment: @Igor That was my question. What about the performance of a date-to-date match as opposed to an int-to-int match on a join?

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's what I thought as well, though others have disagreed with me. I also agree with the performance gain by not needing to convert to/from a date in order to compare, though others have mentioned the notion of sticking to INT for PK's; I feel that a surrogate here would be adding unneeded extra baggage, for a benefit who's existence is kinda sketchy...

Comment: Only you can tell how much the baggage weigh against the benefit of using ints for joins instead of dates... Personally, I use surrogate keys in lookup tables and when the natural keys contain multiple columns. I find it a lot easier to write and maintain joins involving only one column in each table. However, since in your case the natural key storage is actually lower then the surrogate key, I wouldn't bother with a surrogate key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm doing datawarehousing I would go for the surrogate key, and refer that key in your other tables. Joins based on integers are still faster than on date datatypes

Create a table that you fill with dates, something like this ... and use that datekey in your other tables.

```
+---------+-----------+-----+------+----+
|DateKey  |Date       |Year |Month |Day |
+---------+-----------+-----+------+----+
|20170320 |20-03-2017 |2017 |3     |20  |
|20170321 |21-03-2017 |2017 |3     |20  |
|20170322 |22-03-2017 |2017 |3     |20  |
+---------+-----------+-----+------+----+
```

Comment: If you're going to go with a surrogate key then I suggest using an identity column.

Comment: @ZoharPeled if you go with a surrogate key for dates, you lose any semantics, thereby losing the ability to divide or bucket the data based on the PK.

Comment: surrogate keys should not have meaningfull data, they should only be unique. My suggestion was not to use a surrogate key at all...